# Jbuilder - Array to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have an array named sales which is of the following format --

```
2015  January   2403
2015  February  2420
2015  March     2320
2015  April     2230
```

Array Structure - `[[2015, "January", 2403], [2015, "February", 2420]]`

I'm looking to construct the following json response with jbuilder

```
{
 months : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']
 sales :  [2403, 2420, 2320, 2230]
}
```

Things I've tried --

I mapped all the months (and similarly sales) into another array with --

```
@months = @sales.map {|year, month, sales| [month]}
```

And then in jbuilder --

```
{"months":[["February"],["January"],["December"],["November"]]}
```

Which isn't really what I want and neither is it efficient

Some help would be nice.

Comment: please, write full array structure

Comment: I've added it to the question. `[[2015, "January", 2403], [2015, "February", 2420]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In action:

```
array = [[2015, "January", 2403], [2015, "February", 2420]]
@data = array.transpose
```

In .json.jbuilder template:

```
json.months @data[1]
json.sales  @data[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a lovely use case for [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

```
years, months, sales = data.transpose
```

```
{
  "months": months,
  "sales": sales
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

datas = [[2015, "January", 2403], [2015, "February", 2420]]

memo = {months: [], sales: []}

datas.reduce(memo) do |memo, data|
  memo[:months] << data[1]
  memo[:sales] << data[2]
  memo
end

puts JSON.generate(memo)
```